# How to avoid update lost problem in snapshot isolation level?

Tags: sql-server, snapshot, isolation-level

How to check if the certain "a" value was updated with another transaction while the current transaction is running before updating it in the Snapshot isolation level?

Comment: The update won't be lost as suggested in the question title. You'll get an error when the snapshot transaction commits if data are changed (optimistic concurrency).

Comment: Please read the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15 and clarify your question if you still have one.